# The role of a transistor in a magnetostrictive oscillator circuit

Tags: sensor, passive-networks

Could someone please explain the role of the transistor in this circuit?

I have a feeling it has to do with the LC circuit but I'm not sure and don't understand completely.

The following is an image of the circuit (the transistor is n-type.

It is used in lots of sensors to detect and generate ultrasonic waves.

[image: Magnetostrictive Oscillator]

Comment: Here’s two videos explain the operation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4Do_yWJt2k

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3nBlCFTVwg

Comment: It's basically a common emitter amplifier.